# Can't create an AsyncNotifierProvider when notifier needs a depenency injection:

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm getting this compiler error in the following provider code:

> The argument type 'AsyncCatNotifier Function(dynamic)' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'AsyncCatNotifier
> Function()'.dartargument_type_not_assignable (new) AsyncCatNotifier
> AsyncCatNotifier({required NetworkService networkService})
> package:coolcatsclient/providers/provider_async_cat.dart

```
class AsyncCatNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<AsyncValue<Cat?>> {
  final NetworkService networkService;

  AsyncCatNotifier({required this.networkService}) : super();

  Future<void> fetchCat(int catId) async {
    try {
      final cat = await networkService.fetchCat(catId);
      state = AsyncData(AsyncData(cat)); // Update state with fetched cat
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      state = AsyncError(error, stackTrace); // Handle errors
    }
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<AsyncValue<Cat?>> build() {
    return const AsyncLoading(); // Default initial state while loading
  }
}

final asyncCatProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose<AsyncCatNotifier, AsyncValue<Cat?>>(
  // compiler error happens here
  (ref) => AsyncCatNotifier(networkService: ref.read(networkServiceProvider)), 
);
```

Comment: Wrap your dependency with a provider so you can watch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind when using `AsyncNotifier`.

1. Do not declare a constructor, the dependencies should be injected in the `build` method. Either by using `Ref.watch` or from the `build` parameters (family).
2. If you want your `AsyncNotifier` to be auto disposed, extends `AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier`, there are also `FamilyAsyncNotifier` and `AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier`. Consider using code generation to avoid dealing with the type of `Notifier`/`Provider`.
3. Do not specify the `AsyncNotifier`'s type argument with `AsyncValue`. The state of an `AsyncNotifier` is `AsyncValue<T>` where `T` is the type argument of the `AsyncNotifier`.
   For instance, your `AsyncCatNotifier` should probably extends `AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier<Cat?>`.
4. I would say returning `AsyncLoading()` inside the `AsyncNotifier`'s `build` method is undesirable most of the time. Instead, initialise the `AsyncNotifier` right a way.
5. If you do not need to mutate the state of the `AsyncNotifier`, consider converting it to a `FutureProvider`.

Below is how I would implement it:

```dart
// A simple provider for other providers to access NetworkService.
final networkServiceProvider = Provider<NetworkService>((ref) {
  return NetworkService();
});

// A simple future auto dispose family provider to fetch a Cat.
final catProvider = AutoDisposeFutureProviderFamily<Cat, int>((ref, catId) async {
  final networkService = ref.watch(networkServiceProvider);
  final cat = await networkService.fetchCat(catId);
  return cat;
});

// To consume the catProvider.
final cat = ref.watch(catProvider(1));
return cat.when(
          data: (cat) => Text('Cat id: ${cat.id}'),
          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error: $error'),
        ),
```

Below is a `Dog` version with code generation. Notice how it let you

- Avoid dealing with different `Notifier`/`Provider`'s type, you do not have to choose between `AsyncNotifier`/`AutoDisposeAsyncNotifier`/`FamilyAsyncNotifier`/`AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier`
- Define multiple family parameters, supports named parameters and default value.

```dart
@riverpod
NetworkService networkService(NetworkServiceRef ref) {
  return NetworkService();
}

@riverpod
FutureOr<Dog> dog(
  DogRef ref, {
  required int dogId,
}) async {
  final networkService = ref.watch(networkServiceProvider);
  final dog = await networkService.fetchDog(dogId);
  return dog;
}

final dog = ref.watch(dogProvider(dogId: 1));
```

Comment: this works, thanks much! Also appreciate the code gen version, I just started fooling around with code gen, I'll try this and let you know how it goes.